# auto hide and display of list items

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I'm having difficulty getting this to work right.  I'd like the hover over the "Rentals" to display the submenu of "Properties" and then allow me to mouse down through the submenu items to click the one I want.  Problem is the submenu goes away when I try to mouse over to the "properties" link.

Here's a pic of what the menu is:

[image]

Obviously I've messed something up, but I can't figure it out...any help will be appreciated.

Heres the HTML:

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu-menu">    
    <li id="ML_2" class="menu-item">
        <a class="button" href="#">
            <div class="title">Rentals</div>
            <div class="arrow">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="L_RENTALS"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
                                            
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" top: 130px; display: none;">
            <li class="menu-item" id="L_PROPERTIES" ><a href="#">Properties</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="L_AVAILABILITY_CALENDAR"><a href="#">Availability Calendar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
<ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu-menu li ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu-menu li ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: none;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #424242;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#menu-menu li ul li a:hover {
    background: #dfdcdc;
}


a.button  div.icon div {background-position-x: 0px;
    border:0;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    background-size: 30px;
    background-position: 0;

    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;

}

.menu-item div.title{width:100px;float:left;text-align:left;}
.menu-item div.arrow{width:20px;float:left;}
.menu-item div.icon{padding-left: 20px;}
```

Javascript/jquery:

```
$("#menu-menu li").on("mouseenter", function (e) {
    
    //hide other submenus that may be open
    $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
    
    var elePos = $(this).position();
    $(this).find("ul").css({"top":elePos.top+79});
    $(this).find("ul").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve ?

```js
$("#menu-menu > .menu-item").on("mouseenter", function(e) {

  //hide other submenus that may be open
  $(".dropdown-menu").hide();

  var elePos = $(this).position();
  $(this).find("ul").css({
    "top": elePos.top + 79
  });
  $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").show();
});

$("#menu-menu > .menu-item").on("mouseleave", function(e) {
  $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").hide();
});
```

```css
#menu-menu li ul {
  display: none;
}

#menu-menu li ul li a {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #424242;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#menu-menu li ul li a:hover {
  background: #dfdcdc;
}

a.button div.icon div {
  background-position-x: 0px;
  border: 0;
  background-position-y: 0px;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: 0;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.menu-item div.title {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.menu-item div.arrow {
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.menu-item div.icon {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu" id="menu-menu">
  <li id="ML_2" class="menu-item">
    <a class="button" href="#">
      <div class="title">Rentals</div>
      <div class="arrow">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="icon">
        <div class="L_RENTALS"></div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="top: 130px; display: none; ">
      <li class="menu-item " id="L_PROPERTIES "><a href="# ">Properties</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item " id="L_AVAILABILITY_CALENDAR "><a href="# ">Availability Calendar</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I see the selector change...thank you for the help!  This worked perfectly!!!

Comment: Sorry for not adding explanation... I was not sure if you were looking for this exact thing. Cheers!